# postgres min/max group by day of week from date range

Tags: postgresql, group-by, dayofweek

Hi I have tables like this which has one-to-one relation

**report_sites**

```
id | date
1  | 2016-11-02 10:00:00
2  | 2016-11-02 11:00:00
3  | 2016-11-02 12:00:00
4  | 2016-11-03 17:00:00
5  | 2016-11-03 16:00:00
```

**report_services**

```
id | min_serving_time | max_serving_time | report_site_id
1  | 00:00:30.094     | 00:15:30.662     | 1
2  | 00:00:07.566     | 00:07:49.72      | 2
3  | 00:00:07.787     | 00:26:27.587     | 3
```

I want to select **MIN(min_serving_time) MAX(max_serving_time)** from a date range group by weekday like this

```
weekday | min       | max
sunday  | 00:00:05  | 00:08:55
monday  | 00:01:51  | 00:05:21
tuesday |           |
```

I can count the rows of weekdays like this but how do i aggregate the value

```
select    
count(extract(dow from report_sites.date) = 1 or null) as monday,
count(extract(dow from report_sites.date) = 2 or null) as tuesday,
count(extract(dow from report_sites.date) = 3 or null) as wednesday,    
count(extract(dow from report_sites.date) = 4 or null) as thursday,    
count(extract(dow from report_sites.date) = 5 or null) as friday   
 from report_sites 
 inner join "report_services" 
 on "report_sites"."id" = "report_services"."report_site_id"
where report_sites.date >='2016-11-02' 
and 
report_sites.date<='2016-11-07'
```

Thank you for your any help and suggestions.

Comment: You're already extracting the DOW, so group by that and use min/max normally. If you want the result to include monday/tuesday/... and not 1/2/... then you need either a big CASE thing or preferrably do it in the presentation layer

Comment: you mean group by all week days?